# Prevent AutoCompleteTextView dropdown from appearing

Tags: cursor, drop-down-menu, autocompletetextview

**The intro**

I am using `AutoCompleteTextView` in one of my project. The data is brought in the adapter from a cursor using `runQueryOnBackgroundThread`. My layout consists in the AutoComplete TextView (3 letter threshold) and a button with Search. Basically the user has 2 choices: fast type search term and press Search button or Type a bit slower and wait for the dropdown to offer suggestions.

**The problem**

Sometimes when the user quickly presses the Search button, the dropdown of the AutocompleteTextView is displayed while is not needed anymore. Is there a way for me, on Search button onClick() to:
1. stop the `runQueryOnBackgroundThread`
2. prevent/disable the display of dropdown

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can :

- [Dismiss the drop-down](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView.html#dismissDropDown%28%29) when the search button is pressed.
- Set the [threshold](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView.html#setThreshold%28int%29) for the minimum number of characters before which you fire the query/show the drop down

Comment: In the end a combination of what you said + clearListSelection() + clearFocus() made the AutoCompleteTextView behave as I wanted it. Thanks for guidance.